# Bytearray sum in python

Tags: python, sum, arrays

I'm using bytearrays in python 2.7 in order to parse a data stream coming from a serial port. I'm facing a strange behavior: I'm trying to compute a checksum of the received packet in order to check its validity, but I'm having issues with the `sum()` function over a bytearray. I would have expected that, being a bytearray an array of bytes it would sum every byte with each other, right? Only it doesn't..

For example: I have this packet

```
str = '200a02daffe0fe3d140500f6fff6ff6df42c0aabfe'
b = bytearray(str)
```

Summing its content outputs:

```
sum(b)
3263
```

The correct result would be

```
2915
```

at least this is what the calculator says.
This function:

```
def somma_hex(str):
    s = 0
    for i in range(0,len(str)-1,2):
        s += int(byte[i:i+2],16)
```

outputs the correct value, 2915.

It's no big deal, I can use the simple function I wrote instead of the `sum()` but I was wondering, what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: You're summing a bytearray of hex digits. Of course the answer will be wrong. Try using `binascii` to decode the hex to bytes first.

Comment: Decoding actually did the trick. `sum(bytearray(str.decode("hex")))` gives the correct output.

Comment: FWIW, `bytearray` has a [fromhex](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.fromhex) method

Answer (score 1):

Bytearray has 42 8-bit elements which parsed by sum().
In somma_hex you split it into two-bytes chunks and parse them as 16-bit integer.
The facts are obvious.

Comment: I'm sorry, the code I posted wasn't clear enough, in `somma_hex()` i'm passing the hex string, so summing two characters at a time actually results in 1 byte